# Reset scores of Redis sorted set after zremrangebyscore

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, software-distribution

I'm using Redis sorted set to keep some values in order. for example:

```
score | data
0     |  a
1     |  b
2     |  c
3     |  d
```

In some situations of my app, I have to remove some of the entries. for example, I delete scores 1 and 2 members:

```
score | data
0     |  a
3     |  d
```

I want to change the above to:

```
score | data
0     |  a
1     |  d
```

How can I do this?

please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your score always start from 0, and each new element's score is always equal to the size of the set? In another words, are your scores always in the following pattern: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4,...?

Comment: @for_stack yes it's exactly 0,1,2,3,....

Answer (score 2):

I think it's not possible to use a sorted list in Redis like an indexed array.

If you want to have a sorted list with a sequential score you should take care of it yourself so after every delete, you can overwrite your sorted list with new scores.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you don't need the score, instead, you need the rank.

You can keep a monotonically increasing counter, which starting from 0, and each time when you need to add an element to the set, call `incr` on the counter to get a score, and insert the element into the set. So that, each new element will always has the largest score, i.e. new element will rank lower than old elements.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> incr counter
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd set 1 a
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> incr counter
(integer) 2
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd set 2 b
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> incr counter
(integer) 3
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd set 3 c
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> incr counter
(integer) 4
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd set 4 d
```

You can use `ZREMRANGEBYRANK` to remove elements, and `ZRANK` to get the rank of each element (the rank always start from 0).

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zremrangebyrank set 1 2
(integer) 2                              <------- remove b and c
127.0.0.1:6379> zrank set a
(integer) 0
127.0.0.1:6379> zrank set d
(integer) 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice but it can't solve my issue. My app gets some data from a server that has indexes and the order of this data is important. On the other hand, sometimes one can be deleted, one can be modified, and sometimes some data can be deleted and indexes must be reset.

Answer (score 0):

After searching and hard work, I found the solution.

You can use Lua script and EVAL command:

```
EVAL 
"
redis.call('ZREMRANGEBYSCORE', KEYS[1], KEYS[2], KEYS[2]);
local otherMembers = redis.call('ZRANGEBYSCORE', KEYS[1], KEYS[2], 1/0);
for k, v in ipairs(otherMembers) do
redis.call('ZINCRBY', KEYS[1], -1], v);
"
2 key index;
```